# Is there any information about the 1st Bn, the Royal Sussex Regiment at Peshawar being in Cliffden during 1917?

Tags: 1910s, birthplace, army, india

I would like to find out more about Cliffden, in Peshawar in the year 1917.

Allow me to provide some background information:

- My wife's [great grandfather](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15230/8882) was serving in the 1st Bn, the Royal Sussex Regiment at Peshawar in India.
- Her grandfather was born in 1914. According to his birth certificate he was born in Peshawar and the informant was "Officer in charge, Station Family Hospital Peshawar.
- He was baptised at St Johns Church Peshawar and that entry confirmed his parents were living in Peshawar.

---

Recently I found a [1921 Census Entry](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/18771/8882) in Ireland for her great grandfather. It indicated that he had three children. Their ages last birthday:

- 1
- 3
- 7

The oldest child must have been my wife's grandfather (as it calculates to 1914). But, this new information indicated that her grandfather had two more siblings. The middle one would have been born about 1918. Based on the information provided to the linked questions it was clear to me that this brother must have been born in India too.

After some research I found a couple of citations / sources:

- [Gro Army Birth Indices (1881 To 1965)](https://www.findmypast.co.uk/transcript?id=BMD%2FOVS%2FBARM%2F000281%2F100)
- [British India Office Births & Baptisms](https://www.findmypast.co.uk/transcript?id=BL%2FBIND%2FB%2F57314)

According to the first link it specified Peshawar, so I ordered that birth certificate and it was indeed her grandfathers brother:

- The 1st Bn, the Royal Sussex Regiment at Peshawar in India.
- Robert Henry Arthur Baker
- 30 April 1917
- Place: Cliffden
- Informant: The Officer commanding Station Family Hospital Cliffden.

His baptism:

- 17 May 1917
  Murree, Holy Trinity

I found this map which I think shows the correct Cliffden, but I am not sure:

[image]

Do you think that the station family hospital is the one and the same?
Is there are information about this regiments time at Cliffden?

Comment: Before anyone suggests War Diaries, I believe that War Diaries were only kept in theatres of war, and India was not a theatre of war.